# pyinstaller package GUI application

Tags: tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my application to send to people as a stand alone application.

I have tried to use pyinstaller by typing:
pyinstaller --onefile TimeDomainAnalysis.py

This completes and gives me an executable file, but it will not open and returns the attached error message[error message on double clicking the .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DoNW.png)

Part of my GUI code (the bit that refernences the picture) is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkMessageBox
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,         NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

# Each class is a frame in the root main window
class HomeFrame(object):
"""docstring for HomeFrame"""
def __init__(self, root):   # constructor places the widgets in the home     frame.  Each instance (self) is a new window placed in the main window
    super(HomeFrame, self).__init__()
    self.root=root      #oull the root window from the input constructor
    self.root.attributes("-topmost", False)
    self.root.title("Wave Analyzer App")
    self.Frame1=Frame(self.root)    #Create the home frame
    self.Frame1.pack()  #pack the frame.  It must be on a new line to be a     referencable object
    lab=Label(self.Frame1,text='Time Domain Wave Analyzer', font=("Helvetica", 30)).pack()  #label object within the frame that is not dynamic or to be passed to other instances

    self.But1=Button(self.Frame1,text='Get Started',command=self.B1Click)   #place a button in the frame
    self.But1.pack()

    path = "waves-circles-285359_960_720.jpg"

    #Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

    # load = Image.open("waves-circles-285359_960_720.jpg")
    # render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    IMLab=Label(self.Frame1,text='here i am',image=img)
    IMLab.image = img # You must keep a ref to the image else it gets destroyed!!
    IMLab.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    lab2=Label(self.Frame1,text='By Ben Howey', font=("Helvetica", 12))     #label object within the frame that is not dynamic or to be passed to other instances
    lab2.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

Comment: Does it produce any error when interpreted? Is the image in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Check if you have any hidden imports. In your Python script file, you can search for __import__.
Example:
    module = __import__(name).
If that's the case, try this link: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html
and look under Listing Hidden Imports.

Comment: Also, if you're using --onefile flag, that image could be created in a temp folder. Did you modify your pyinstaller .spec file in anyway?

Comment: I have run the pains taller with success when I comment out all the references to the image.  It only seems to fail when I try to include this.  I am doing this by running pyinstaller --onefile TimeDomainApp.py with the python script and the image in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Adding

```
    def resource_path(self,relative_path):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

to return an absolute file path either in a MEIPASS directory when run from the exe or an absolute file path when run in Python.  Then adding the file to the package by editing the .spec file to add the image file.